# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree in react

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies

Trying add dependencies react but i cannot install any packages. I recently deleted a package-lock.json to resolve ELOCKVERIFY error. I eventually installed the following command of 'npm audit fix' but I still carry the same ERESOLVE error.

npm audit fix

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-simple-typewriter@1.0.13
npm ERR! node_modules/react-simple-typewriter
npm ERR!   react-simple-typewriter@"^1.0.13" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-11T19_07_29_767Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

`react-simple-typewriter` version `1.0.13` requires version `16.x`, while you have version `17.0.2`.

Either upgrade `react-simple-typewriter` to a version that supports React `17.x` (if there is one) or  downgrade React to `16.x`

Comment: I used the below code to solve for this problem
npm install --save react@16.14.0 react-dom@16.14.0 
Thanks for your help I can now install other packages to my react app. I know have to remove  moderate vulnerabilities